# @VisibleForTesting() function not triggering compile error for production code when being used

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

For Android App, I tried to use `@VisibleForTesting()` as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting

```
@VisibleForTesting()
void myFunction(String id) {
    doSomething(id);
}
```

Tried it both for Java and Kotlin code.

I explicitly having the production call the public function that is annotated with `@VisibleForTesting()`. When I compile, I don't see any error or warning thrown to prevent me from using it in Production code.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What makes you think it should throw an error or warning during compilation?

Comment: Just because it's visible for testing, doesn't mean it shouldn't be used in non-testing code. The opposite is true. There is no value in code that is only invoked from tests - just remove it. In good code, is always some non-test code that accesses a @VisibleForTesting method.

Answer (score 7):

This will be asserted by Android's Lint, and defaults to a warning.

You may change that by increasing the severity level to error in your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        error("VisibleForTests")
    }
}
```